# Regular Expression pattern storing in array

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I am new to perl and want to read a file in which IP are stored , i want to grep these IP and store in array , i am able to write the regex for this but out of three ips it always stores last ip of file in array , please help someone my code and file is like below.

my input file have follwing contents

> Hi praveen how are10.23.54.86
>
> 10.87.98.65
>
> 10.98.76.54

my script o/p is

> /pearl$ ./par.pl sdp.txt
>
> 10.98.76.54

and code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (INPUT,$ARGV[0]) || die "Can not open file:$!";

$i=0;

while(<INPUT>)
{
  $line=$_;
  ($arr,$arr1,$arr2)=($line=~m/\d+[\.]\d+[\.]\d+[\.]\d+/g);
}


close(INPUT);

print $arr,"\n";
```

I tried with array and as well as variable but same results its only stores last value.

Comment: I'm a Java developer so maybe I'm bringing the wrong idiom to this Perl question: aren't you supposed to declare/initialize your arr BEFORE the while loop and inside just accumulate the result?

Comment: @targumon That's optional in perl, it's good practice to `use strict` in longer scripts in which case you would have to do that.  However perl supports one liners were it's nice to have auto initialization by default.

Comment: @Benj it is optional, but it should be done in general. This is not a one-liner, so `strict` and `warnings` should be enabled.

Comment: @simbabque Indeed, that's covered by "good practice" no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the Perl Module [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2011121001/lib/Regexp/Common.pm) to match the IPs, as it's been well-developed for this purpose:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

my @IPs;

while (<>) {
    my ($IP) = /($RE{net}{IPv4})/;
    push @IPs, $IP if $IP;
}

print "$_\n" for @IPs;
```

Output from your data set:

```
10.23.54.86
10.87.98.65
10.98.76.54
```

A valid IP on a line is captured and placed into `$IP`. The next line `push`es an IP onto `@IPs` if `$IP` contains one.  Finally, the elements of `@IPs` are `print`ed, if any.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As you're reading one  line at a time, and each line has  only one address, of
course you have  only one output since  the output is printed  after the loop,
not inside it on each iteration.

- Use `<>`
- Avoid unecessary variables (like `$i`)
- Enable warnings
- You most likely want to use an array to store your IPs

In the following code, your IPs will be stored in `@ips`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @ips;

while (<>) {
    # not the optimal regex for IPs, I just simplifyied yours
    push @ips, m/(?:\d+\.){3}\d+/g;
}

print "@ips\n";
# --- or ---
print "$_\n" foreach @ips;
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two problems:

1. You appear to be filling 3 variables, not 4 (Unless you don't want the last number?)
2. Your regex doesn't specify any capture groups so you're not saving out any values from the matched string.

You want something like:

```
while(<INPUT>)
{
  if( ($arr,$arr1,$arr2,$arr3) = /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/g )
  {
    print "$arr $arr1 $arr2 $arr3\n";
  }
}
```

Or if you want to treat the matched numbers as a list try this:

```
while(<>)
{
  chomp;
  if( @array = /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/g )
  {
    print @array;
  }
}
```

Comment: @fxzuz __Never__ ever edit a question to change its indentation style, that is completely personal; and unless it's not readable, it won't contribute to anything.